# Date field keeps switching to the next day's date

Tags: sharepoint-list

I have a list item where, when I enter today's date and click Save, it switches to the next day's date. Any ideas why this happens and how to fix it?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to check the site collection time zone?

Answer (score 1):

This [article](http://itgroove.net/brainlitter/2012/04/09/how-to-set-regionaltime-zone-settings-in-sharepoint/) may assist. From recollection the issue can occur if your personal user regional settings are different to the site collection regional settings. The article demonstrates how to set both it is for SharePoint 2010 but i similar for 2013/2016/online